# Pipe blocking drywall placement

Tags: plumbing, drywall, walls

I'm new here

I'm redoing my 2nd floor Bathroom and this is my first major project. when the plumber redid the plumbing in the wall (coming from 3rd floor and joining waste from 2nd floor bath and down to drain) he put the pipe sticking out so that I cant put on the drywall.

[image: Pipe view]

I only removed the old tiles on the lower half of the wall and Don't want to remove the lath and plaster.

I don't want to bring the plumber back and I don't want to add another layer to the entire wall. What can I do?

[image]

There is a door immediately to the left of the area shown. (you can see the casing on the bottom of the second picture)

I'm only tiling the bottom part so my only thought is that perhaps the tile can make the difference in depth not noticeable. but I'm not sure how that would work against the door.

I'm new to this so any advise would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Without changing the plumbing you could build the wall out just enough to clear the pipe, then use a thinner cement backer board with the backer board and tile. It should hold up ok.

Comment: You might want to call the electrician back too. That wiring is atrocious.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the existing cast iron nub is the problem more than the pvc.  If you are covering in tile you can cut out a hole in your sheetrock or wonderboard this will save you 1/2 inch.  Then you can tile right over the area.  You may have to build the wall out some to do this but there is no other way.  End result will be your tile will be only a tile thickness past the nub on your finish wall.

Answer (score 0):

i second the electrician coming back.  there is no way that meets code.  even in kazakhstan.

other than that, just fur out the studs to get whatever clearance you need and then add your finishes.  easy peezy

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ed Beal & Personal Privacy Advocate on the furring out if you don't want a "decorative" hump. Do a 2x4 flat on top of the inside corner one & the middle stud to whatever & do nothing to the door one. The wall will be slightly angled, but nice & flat.

The only thing the plumber could do is charge you more money to go up to the cast iron's next hub & do PVC here. Cast iron is extremely heavy so his setup here is perfect otherwise & he couldn't have done it any other way.

But, see if he thinks he can do the support at the ceiling or above & what it would cost. Or, if he's cool with you or he grinding it down a 1/4" or even 1/2" (this depends on the load of pipe above & **ONLY** if it's just a vent stack above this bath). It might be worth a few extra bucks & no-one ever has to deal with it again.